How to hide PrimeVue carousel navigation buttons and indicators on mobile?
I have a problem trying to hide carousel navigation buttons and indicators on mobile.
I tried to use responsiveOptions for this, but it didn't work. The array of options for responsiveness looks like this:
const responsiveOptions = ref([
  {
    breakpoint: '1200px',
    numVisible: 3,
    numScroll: 1
  },
  {
    breakpoint: '767px',
    numVisible: 2,
    numScroll: 1,
    showNavigators: false
  },
  {
    breakpoint: '475px',
    numVisible: 1,
    numScroll: 1,
    showIndicators: false
  },
])

My carousel component:
<Carousel :value="products" :num-visible="4" :num-scroll="1"
          :responsive-options="responsiveOptions" circular
          :autoplay-interval="3000"
>
<template v-slot:previousicon>
  <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
    chevron_left
  </span>
</template>
<template #item="slotProps">
  <div class="card position-relative product-card h-100">
    <div class="offer position-absolute top-0 left-0 d-flex flex-column p-2">
      <span class="offer-hit mb-2" v-if="slotProps.data.hit">Hit</span>
      <span class="offer-new" v-if="slotProps.data.new">New</span>
    </div>
    <img :src="slotProps.data.image" class="card-img-top" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><strong>{{ slotProps.data.title }}</strong></h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{ slotProps.data.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <h5 class="card-title m-0">
        <s><small>{{ slotProps.data.oldPrice }}$</small></s>
        {{ slotProps.data.price }}$
      </h5>
      <button class="btn btn-danger p-1">
        <span class="material-symbols-sharp" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
          shopping_cart
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<template v-slot:nexticon>
  <span class="material-symbols-sharp">
    chevron_right
  </span>
</template>
</Carousel>

I know I can use CSS to do this, but I want to find out if there are any in-built options/methods I could use to achieve the desired result.
If you need something else to understand my question, feel free to ask.

You need to use a v-if directive if you don‘t want to use a media query

@dbzx10299, even if I use the directive on the icons, the navigation buttons are still there, taking up space. And I don't have direct access to those elements, they're a part of the kit. Sorry if you meant something else.

looking at the api, CarouselResponsiveOptions[] takes in three possible options: breakpoint, numVisible, and numScroll. showIndicators does not belong in the responsiveOptions array.

@dbzx10299, thank you very much! I didn't notice this for some reason. So, are there any other ways to achieve this with built-in features of PrimeVue?

One way to do this is to create a Vue composable if you are concerned about reusing this code.
export const useMediaQuery = () => {
  const isMobile = ref(null)
  const mql = ref(null)

  function update(e) {
    isMobile.value = e.matches
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    mql.value = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)')
    isMobile.value = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1024px)').matches
    mql.value.addEventListener('change', update)
  })

  onUnmounted(() => {
    mql.value.removeEventListener('change', update)
  })

  return { isMobile }
}

Then you could use this in your component.
<script setup>
import { useMediaQuery } from './useMediaQuery.js'

const { isMobile } = useMediaQuery()
</script>

<template>
  <Carousel :showIndicators="isMobile ? false : true"/>
</template>


I've just found out that isMobile ? false : true can be simplified to !isMobile.
